# Check my site in different browser version for mobile friendliness

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, mobile

actually this is something that I have no idea what to do actually, what I need to do is that I need to check my site for mobile friendliness on different mobile browsers on their different versions.

like this
android browser
version 1 ok
version 2 ok
version 3 not ok
ext....

similarly on different mobile browsers 
what I have till now. I tested for this on browser stack but I can only find limited no. of browsers and their versions.
If it happens that anyone knows any particular site or url that relates to my concern please comment or answer.

links that I know are: 
browser stack.com
and http://webtrends.about.com/od/mobileweb20/tp/list_of_mobile_web_browsers.htm
and test mobile etc.

but i need a detailed analysis..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/

You can use this to test mobile friendliness.

Here are a few more websites to help:
https://validator.w3.org/mobile/

- https://validator.w3.org/mobile/
- http://mobiletest.me/ - This one lets you choose a device to emulate the browser